# Understanding categorical variables in ZINB and other models

Tags: multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model

This might sound very basic question but not getting the logic from the outcome or unless I need to code my categorical variables in a different way.

I am trying to model risk factors for a disease (orf) in sheep with dependent variable being number of disease cases/sheep affected in a given farm. I have over 700 farms.

I found Zero Inflated Negative Binomial model was fitting the data better in comparison to other models. Count from the data shows that there were more disease cases based on variable Breed coded as 1 for pure. However the ZINB output shows that Breed 2(mixed) is significant. I understand that there has to be a set point/base which forms part of the estimate in which case I take that would be Breed 1 looking at the output.

From the output bellow the variable thistle is understandable to me given that I used 0 to represent farms with no thistle.

Could someone help explain why Breed with less disease count shows to be significant or do I need to recode the variable?

```r
    Call:
    zeroinfl(formula = Cases2012 ~ Precip + Altitude + Tempmax + 
     Tempmin + Stocking.Density2012 + 
     as.factor(Lambing.Management) + 
     as.factor(Farming.Practise) + as.factor(Breed) + 
     as.factor(Thistles), data = orf, dist = "negbin", 
     link = "logit")
    
    Pearson residuals:
          Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
    -0.723567 -0.477644 -0.416815 -0.008045 13.661070 
    
    Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
                                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)                     6.622260   2.466488   2.685 0.007255 ** 
    Precip                         -0.005894   0.006103  -0.966 0.334142    
    Altitude                       -0.003771   0.001265  -2.980 0.002884 ** 
    Tempmax                        -0.022739   0.234957  -0.097 0.922901    
    Tempmin                        -0.087032   0.174618  -0.498 0.618191    
    Stocking.Density2012           -0.003405   0.007414  -0.459 0.646053    
    as.factor(Lambing.Management)2 -0.158969   0.234573  -0.678 0.497967    
    as.factor(Lambing.Management)3  0.082626   0.172778   0.478 0.632493    
    as.factor(Farming.Practise)2   -0.050801   0.143372  -0.354 0.723090    
    as.factor(Breed)1              -0.522006   0.140187  -3.724 0.000196 ***
    as.factor(Thistles)0.5         -1.309976   0.964278  -1.359 0.174303    
    as.factor(Thistles)1           -0.174010   0.376072  -0.463 0.643577    
    as.factor(Thistles)2            0.141963   0.369524   0.384 0.700846    
    as.factor(Thistles)3           -0.302203   0.383030  -0.789 0.430124    
    as.factor(Thistles)4           -0.251766   0.434042  -0.580 0.561881    
    as.factor(Thistles)5            0.076817   0.483300   0.159 0.873714    
    Log(theta)                     -0.451317   0.090387  -4.993 5.94e-07 ***
    
    Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
    (Intercept)                     -2.352151   2.198755  -1.070   0.2847  
    Precip                          -0.007893   0.006801  -1.161   0.2458  
    Altitude                         0.001192   0.001352   0.882   0.3780  
    Tempmax                          0.378948   0.205915   1.840   0.0657 .
    Tempmin                         -0.370911   0.182779  -2.029   0.0424 *
    Stocking.Density2012            -0.004753   0.008069  -0.589   0.5558  
    as.factor(Lambing.Management)2   0.221767   0.251134   0.883   0.3772  
    as.factor(Lambing.Management)3   0.051169   0.190990   0.268   0.7888  
    as.factor(Farming.Practise)2    -0.093695   0.162217  -0.578   0.5635  
    as.factor(Breed)1               -0.318733   0.158142  -2.015   0.0439 *
    as.factor(Thistles)0.5         -13.291239 645.077399  -0.021   0.9836  
    as.factor(Thistles)1             0.434342   0.463638   0.937   0.3489  
    as.factor(Thistles)2             0.452203   0.461242   0.980   0.3269  
    as.factor(Thistles)3             0.201490   0.471258   0.428   0.6690  
    as.factor(Thistles)4             0.516865   0.527709   0.979   0.3274  
    as.factor(Thistles)5             0.006094   0.607234   0.010   0.9920  
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 
    
    Theta = 0.6368 
    Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 40 
    Log-likelihood: -2409 on 33 Df
```

```
Sample data:

    Breed   Farming.Pr Lambing.Mgt   Cases2012
       1        0         1            0
       0        0         1            0
       1        1         1            8
       1        1         1            73
       1        0         1            0
       1        1         1            26
       1        1         2            0
       1        0         1            45
       0        1         1            0
       1        1         1            22
       0        1         1            0
       0        1         3            0
       1        1         3            0
       1        1         1            6
       0        1         1            539
       1        0         1            0
       1        0         1            0
       1        1         3            0
       0        0         1            0
       1        0         1            10
       0        0         1            0
       0        0         1            0
       1        1         3            0
       0        0         2            35
       0        0         1            2100
       1        1         1            0
       0        1         1            1550
       1        1         1            0
       1        0         1            1
       1        0         1            67
       1        0         1            0
       1        0         1            0
       0        0         3            0
       0        0         3            0
       0        1         1            0
       1        0         1            0
```

Answer (score 0):

The baseline related to factor Breed is pure(1). For that reason, the fact that Breed 2(mixed) is significant, just indicates that the difference between levels 1 and 2 is significant. It indicates nothing related to greater expected incidence in one or another. However, if you check the coefficient (-0.31), it indicates that the odds is in Mixed breed (level 2) is less than the odds in pure breed (level 1).

Comment: Thanks@ Eric Chacon, so in this case should I just use log odds to explain my findings? The aim was to ser if there are any significant associations between the  disease and the variables.